# CMake can not find PythonLibs while building OpenCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, opencv

so Im trying to cross-compile OpenCV for an arm device and while running cmake, I noticed in the output that the PythonLibs were not found. I have both Python2 and Python3 libs installed in my system.

Here is the output

> -- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2.7 (found suitable version "2.7.12", minimum required is "2.7")
>
> > -- Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing:  PYTHON_LIBRARIES PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS) (Required is exact version "2.7.12")
>
> -- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found suitable version "3.5.2", minimum required is "3.4")
>
> > -- Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing:  PYTHON_LIBRARIES PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS) (Required is exact version "3.5.2")

Towards the end of the output, I also noticed this

> Python 2:
>
> > Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.12)
>
> Python 3:
>
> > Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.5.2)
>
> Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7

From this I could conclude that the Python bindings were not built. If someone had any suggestion on how I can fix this, I would be happy to listen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to compile something that is simple requesting the DEV packages, you have only the Python interpreters packages, in Raspberry PI you must have `python-dev` and `python3-dev` for example, if you are using Raspberry PI try to run:

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-dev python3-dev
```

Then you will pass this step, if there come another errors make new posts.

A good and simple tutorial on how to compile OpenCV for Raspberry PI you found here:
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/18/install-guide-raspberry-pi-3-raspbian-jessie-opencv-3/